# Update statement in Realm android

Tags: android, realm

How should i update a already existing value using realm DB in android?

I have been trying to update it but it is adding as a new value only not overwritting it

Comment: Please show us your efforts(the relevant part of your code, where you are trying to update). Only then we can tell you where's the problem.

Comment: **see full answer with example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933229/update-realm-object-android**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Another way to update an existing object with all its fields in your Realm DB is using the method `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate()`:

```
Object obj = new Object();
obj.setField1(field1);
obj.setField2(field2);
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(obj);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

If your object has a **Primary Key**, this method will update the object automatically without duplicate objects :)

More info: [copyToRealmOrUpdate()](http://realm.io/docs/java/0.79.0/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyToRealmOrUpdate-E-)

Comment: You actually don't get any benefit from beginning the transaction before you have your object created. So I would suggest to move that first line down before the copyToRealmOrUpdate() to make it clear.

Comment: This answer is outdated? `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(obj);` is not needed if you are working with realm. It would be needed only if you are using Retrofit for example: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#retrofit

Comment: @MicroR So, what is the alternative? How to update an existing value in Realm? (I'm getting `Realm Database Error: Value already exists:` if I use `createObject()`).

Comment: What if i don't have a primary key and I still want to update?

Comment: From documentation: "Using primary keys makes it possible to use the copyToRealmOrUpdate() method, which will look for an existing object with this primary key, and update it if one is found"

Comment: @SrikarReddy u because not need a createObject for update.. make a simple constructor with all variables a use createOrUpdate and do not forget realm.close

Comment: is it necessary to use try catch block?

Answer (score 9):

You can use insertOrUpdate method to do this.Hope this helps

```
  Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {

                    objectToEdit.setNewValue("string");
                    realm.insertOrUpdate();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    OrderedRealmCollection<Practice> orderedRealmCollection = 
             realm.where(Practice.class)
            .contains("key", "matchig value")
            .findAll();

    if(orderedRealmCollection.size()!=0){
        Practice practice = orderedRealmCollection.first();
        Realm.getDefaultInstance().executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                practice.setUpdate_practice_steps(""+steps);
                realm.insertOrUpdate(practice);
            }
        });
    }
```