# Update statement in Realm

Tags: android, realm

I have `VisitingCardPOJO` form table. I want update single entry say where  **no=3**

VisitingCardPOJO.java

```
public class VisitingCardPOJO extends RealmObject {

   @PrimaryKey private int no;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public int getNo() {
        return no;
    }

    public void setNo(int no) {
        this.no = no;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the solution as and It worked

```
 public void updateNewCard(Realm realm, VisitingCardPOJO card) {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        VisitingCardPOJO toEdit = realm.where(VisitingCardPOJO.class)
                .equalTo("no", card.getNo()).findFirst();
        toEdit.setName(card.getName());
        toEdit.setAddress(card.getAddress());
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
```

see [demo for Realm](https://github.com/NileshJarad/android-mvp-material-and-realm)

Comment: @Nilesh What if i have to update only one column, not the complete object?

Comment: @BSTKaal do it this way anyway. Realm will check which properties need to be updated

Comment: I think you have to check toEdit != null before update the value.

Answer (score 6):

The actual right way to do it is this

```
public void updateNewCard(Realm realm, VisitingCardPOJO card) {
    final int no = card.getNo();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            VisitingCardPOJO toEdit = realm.where(VisitingCardPOJO.class)
                .equalTo("no", no).findFirst();
            if(toEdit != null) {
                toEdit.setName(card.getName());
                toEdit.setAddress(card.getAddress());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to use try catch block?

Comment: what try-catch block?

Comment: Can i update RealmResult without using execute transaction?