# Swift: How to save only new items into the Realm DB and update the existing values

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am currently using Realm for local caching of data in my iOS Swift App. I have a reload function that fetches the data from the server and saves it to the Realm every 20 seconds. But, for users who have more than 100 messages, it is taking a lot of time and by the time it fetches the data and saves it, the function is starting again. I cannot increase the reload time. Is there any way that when I am fetching and saving messages, it saves only the new messages and updates the old messages only if there is a need to so.

Comment: did you check http://stackoverflow.com/q/27223669/6689101

Comment: How do u understand an old message need update or not?

Comment: @zombie I need the implementation for iOS. But, I have the same implementation in place to prevent duplicate values.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan Once the message is saved in Realm, generally there will not be any changes made to it. I have just added to know if there is any possible in doing that. Basically, we only understand it if there is any change in text

Comment: You can try something before the update get all the messages saved then with the 'filter' operator on the array in swift try to exclude all matches and then add the result messages array

Comment: Are you fetching _all_ the messages from the server each time? It would make sense for the request to your server to take a timestamp or message number parameter, and have the server only send down the messages that haven't been previously sent down before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

I have an API call from the server to check if the message is read. I am using that call and fetching only the messages that are unread and saving them to the Realm.

So, this way I only fetch the new messages. This method is working perfectly for us.